# Rotation Vector Sensor

Tags: android, rotation, android-sensors

I want to know how to use rotation vector sensor in android development. I couldn't understand how to do this from the android developer official website. I need any book or video that explains this topic for the beginners.

Comment: you can try Professional Android Sensor Programming book by greg Millete.

Answer (score 2):

A good introduction outlining the various sensors under android is the [devolopers site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html). 
After this you could go on reading about [position](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html), [motion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html) or [environmental](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_environment.html) sensors, depending on what you want. 
Pictures of the two coordinate systems related by the rotation vector:

- [smartphone-fixed frame](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html#sensors-coords)
- [android-refrence frame](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html#sensors-motion-rotate)

The code examples are basic, so in case you find it hard to comprehend, there might be lacking knowledge in Java itself or the mechanical background. 
The [Java beginners guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071809252) could be a starting point or [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sensors.htm) to go straight for the sensors. More about mechanics on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation)